# extracting data from json array in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

My json fetched from the movie database api looks like this :

```
{
  "id": 550,
  "cast": [
    {
      "cast_id": 4,
      "character": "The Narrator",
      "credit_id": "52fe4250c3a36847f80149f3",
      "gender": 2,
      "id": 819,
      "name": "Edward Norton",
      "order": 0,
      "profile_path": "/eIkFHNlfretLS1spAcIoihKUS62.jpg"
    }
],
  "crew": [
    {
      "credit_id": "56380f0cc3a3681b5c0200be",
      "department": "Writing",
      "gender": 0,
      "id": 7469,
      "job": "Screenplay",
      "name": "Jim Uhls",
      "profile_path": null
    },
{
      "credit_id": "57fe1e549251410699007177",
      "department": "Costume & Make-Up",
      "gender": 1,
      "id": 1693424,
      "job": "Assistant Costume Designer",
      "name": "Mirela Rupic",
      "profile_path": "/5z0I2eRwBrJjSv27ig4VnU0lmCZ.jpg"
    }
    ]
    }
```

So the object has fields id int, cast[] and crew[].
i need to extract data from crew[] for each 'parent' id: `id,crew_id,job,name` in the same pandas dataframe. So far i was using `df=json.normalize(crew)` to get all contents from `crew`. How am i going to get data from the arrays?My dataframe will look like this:

```
id     crew_id     job                       name
550     7469      Screenplay                 Jim Uhls
550    1693424  Assistant Costume Designer  Mirela Rupic
551   someid.    somejob.                   some name
etc.   etc.        etc                       etc
```

Comment: the first row has 4 for the crew_id; however in the dictionary, 4 is assigned to the cast id.

Comment: bingo. was passing it in as a dataframe. switched to dict and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a list comprehension to get the details; since the main id is constant, the only parts that iterate are the details in the crew section of the dictionary.

```
 M = [(d['id'],
      i['id'],
      i['job'],
      i['name'])
      for i in d['crew']]

df = pd.DataFrame(M, columns=['id','crew_id','job','name'])

    id  crew_id      job                     name
0   550 7469    Screenplay                  Jim Uhls
1   550 1693424 Assistant Costume Designer  Mirela Rupic
```

Comment: it throws a ''TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'' exception

Comment: [(d['id'], i['id'], i['job'], i['name'])  for i in d['crew']] . runs fine on my end. the data is a dictionary right?